# Swift body method within viewmodifier : puzzled about how the application is different for .shadow() and .font

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

Why does `shadow()` can be applied for more than 2 times and get updated every time, while for `.font()` even though I put different styling arguments and `.font()` for two times and not updated remaining the same?

```swift
struct LabelStyle: ViewModifier { // receive view => style it up =>  return styled view
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(Font.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 18))
                .modifier(Shadow())
                .font(Font.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 35)) // not becoming 35-sized
                .modifier(differentStyledShadow()) // shadow gets updated
    }
}
```

Comment: shadow() when used the second time does not updates the previous shadow. It creates a new one. Try changing the offset of the second shadow. Then you can see both the shadows. You can check view inspector in Xcode while running the app to check how the properties are applied to the view.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thnx !!

Comment: @SumeshSivan could you please share your comment as an answer because of others benefits

Comment: I have moved my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1):

shadow() when used the second time does not updates the previous shadow. It creates a new one.

Try changing the offset of the second shadow. Then you can see both the shadows.

You can check view inspector in Xcode while running the app to check how the properties are applied to the view.